# Prevent alphanumerics in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

How do I do this with code? I know I can use a `JFormattedTextField`, but I'm making my own library so that `JTextField`s can also do this. Here are the methods I've tried:

1. `OnKeyRelease`: Yes, this is the best method I've found, I replaced all the chars I want with "". But it kinda slow, I mean it still shows the forbidden chars when the key is down, and remove the chars when the key released, just like its event name. Which bothers me.
2. `evt.consume`: I don't know why this method works for anything except numbers and letters, such as Backspace, Home, etc. Any idea how to make this method also work on numbers or letters?

If you could give me a clue or link I would be grateful, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you could give me a clue or link I would be grateful, thanks :)

How about [Text Component Features - Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)?

> To implement a document filter, create a subclass of [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) and then attach it to a document using the `setDocumentFilter` method defined in the `AbstractDocument` class.

This might help:

```
public class NoAlphaNumFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    String notAllowed = "[A-Za-z0-9]";
    Pattern notAllowedPattern = Pattern.compile(notAllowed);
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs,
                        int length, 
                        String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException {

        super.replace(fb, offs, len, "", a); // clear the deleted portion

        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        for (char c : chars) {
            if (notAllowedPattern.matcher(Character.toString(c)).matches()) {
                // not allowed; advance counter
                offs++;
            } else {
                // allowed
                super.replace(fb, offs++, 0, Character.toString(c), a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To apply this to a `JTextField`:

```
((AbstractDocument) myTextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(
  new NoAlphaNumFilter());
```

Comment: I cannot use this for JTextField, can I?

Comment: Where do I have to put that last code in? I put it in my constructor but it doesn't affect my JTextField. And, I also get a caution to cast a into `(javax.swing.text.AttributeText)`, is this correct? Because in `super.replace` method it reads required parameter as `javax.swing.text.AttributeText`, and found `javax.print.attribute.AttributeText`.

Comment: Yes, put it right after you instantiate the `new JTextField`. What are you casting to `AttributeText`? You should be using `javax.swing.text.AttributeSet`; I don't know about any attribute text class... please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to better display your problem.

Comment: Oh my, it's me who import a wrong package, I should import from `javax.swing`, but I used auto import `CTRL+SHIFT+I` so NetBeans imports from `javax.print` class hhehe. After fixing this problem, I found your solution **works** hhehe, thank you so much :)